# count words in a .txt then write the results in the same .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

Im trying to count the amount of words in a text document then write the total back to the .txt

here is how far i've got

```
words = 0
   f = open("count.txt", 'r+')

for wordcount in f.readline().split(" "):
   words += 1


print('number of words ')
print(words)


f.write("number of words ")
f.write(words)
f.close()
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Where am I going wrong?

i feel that `f.write(words)` isn't the correct way to write the total to the txt?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: Could we see the full error message.  Particually on which line it is on.

Comment: Are you using Micropython? If so, on what platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must convert `words` to a string before being able to write it into the file.

```
with open("count.txt", "r+") as f:
    words = len(f.read().split())
    print('number of words ')
    print(words)

    f.write("number of words ")
    f.write(str(words))
```

Moreover:

`readline`reads only one line. Use `read`to read the whole file.

use `len`to count the size of a list, inside of counting it by yourself

use `with`to ensure that the file will be closed

Answer (score 2):

`file.write` accepts only a text buffer, so you need to cast `words` into a string first before writing it to a file:

```
f.write(str(words))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`f.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) requires a string as its argument, unlike [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), which will take any number of objects of any kind, and automatically convert them all into strings for you, and join them up with configurable separators and a configurable ending, and so on.

In other words, `print` is clever and friendly; `write` is a low-level function. So, to make this work with `write`, you have to do the conversion manually.

```
f.write(str(words))
```

But you can also just use `print` instead of calling `f.write`:

```
print(words, file=f)
```

---

Notice that this doesn't do quite the same thing. When you call `print`, by default, it puts a newline at the end. So, this code:

```
print('number of words ')
print(words)
```

… will print out two separate lines:

```
number of words
3
```

And likewise, this code:

```
print('number of words ', file=f)
print(words, file=f)
```

… will add the same two separate lines to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Words has to be converted to string. `File.write()` is what is actually going to write it.

Your new code:

```
f.write("number of words ")
f.write(str(words))
```